# Apollo server subscription not recognizing Async Iterable

Tags: graphql, apollo, publish-subscribe

I'm having an issue with Apollo GraphQL's subscription. When attempting to start the subscription I'm getting this in return:

```
"Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: { pubsub: { ee: [EventEmitter], subscriptions: {}, subIdCounter: 0 }, pullQueue: [], pushQueue: [], running: true, allSubscribed: null, eventsArray: [\"H-f_mUvS\"], return: [function return] }"
```

I have other subscriptions setup and are completely functional - so I can confirm the webserver is setup correctly.

I'm just curious if anyone else has ever ran onto this issue before.

Source code in PR diff (it's an open source project):
https://github.com/astronomer/houston-api/pull/165/files

[error in playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1oQs.png)

Comment: Can you update your questions with the relevant resolver code?

Comment: I added a link to the PR I have opening showing the relevant code that's causing the issue. It's quite involved and may not make total sense without a full context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an issue specific to the PR you posted. I'd be surprised if any of the subscriptions were working as is.

Your `subscribe` function should return an AsyncIterable, as the error states. Since it returns a call to `createPoller`, `createPoller` should return an AsyncIterable. But here's what that function looks like:

```
export default function createPoller(
  func,
  pubsub,
  interval = 5000, // Poll every 5 seconds
  timeout = 3600000 // Kill after 1 hour
) {
  // Gernate a random internal topic.
  const topic = shortid.generate();

  // Create an async iterator. This is what a subscription resolver expects to be returned.
  const iterator = pubsub.asyncIterator(topic);

  // Wrap the publish function on the pubsub object, pre-populating the topic.
  const publish = bind(curry(pubsub.publish, 2)(topic), pubsub);

  // Call the function once to get initial dataset.
  func(publish);

  // Then set up a timer to call the passed function. This is the poller.
  const poll = setInterval(partial(func, publish), interval);

  // If we are passed a timeout, kill subscription after that interval has passed.
  const kill = setTimeout(iterator.return, timeout);

  // Create a typical async iterator, but overwrite the return function
  // and cancel the timer. The return function gets called by the apollo server
  // when a subscription is cancelled.
  return {
    ...iterator,
    return: () => {
      log.info(`Disconnecting subscription ${topic}`);
      clearInterval(poll);
      clearTimeout(kill);
      return iterator.return();
    }
  };
}
```

So `createPoller` creates an AsyncIterable, but then creates a shallow copy of it and returns that. `graphql-subscriptions` uses `iterall`'s `isAsyncIterable` for the check that's producing the error you're seeing. Because of the way `isAsyncIterable` [works](https://github.com/leebyron/iterall/blob/master/index.mjs#L483), a shallow copy won't fly. You can see this for yourself:

```
const { PubSub } = require('graphql-subscriptions')
const { isAsyncIterable } = require('iterall')

const pubSub = new PubSub()
const iterable = pubSub.asyncIterator('test')
const copy = { ...iterable }
console.log(isAsyncIterable(iterable)) // true
console.log(isAsyncIterable(copy)) // false
```

So, instead of returning a shallow copy, `createPoller` should just mutate the `return` method directly:

```
export default function createPoller(...) {
  ...
  iterator.return = () => { ... }

  return iterator
}
```

Comment: Fantastic response, thank you for the time you put into figuring this out. Hugely appreciated!!